# Fuzzing cli utility with afl

Tags: linux

How to use afl to fuzzy cli utilities like parted? For example there is command `parted --script <DISK_PATH> rm <PARTITION_ID>`. How should afl-fuzz command look like and what should be content of testcase file to fuzz `<DISK_PATH>` and `<PARTITION_ID>`?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution - everything I needed to know is described in `experimental/argv_fuzzing/argv-fuzz-inl.h` in afl repository.